# What is wrong with my function? Finding the shortest path using numpy and networkx

Tags: python, function, numpy, for-loop, networkx

so I'm creating a code to calculate the shortest path using networkx. I created a 3D array using numpy and then calculated the shortest path like this:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

arr = np.random.randint(1, 100, size = (2, 5, 5)) #3D array

for i in arr:
    graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
    path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight')
    print(path)
```

Since I'm using two matrix, I got the next output:

```
[0, 1, 3] #path1
[0, 3]    #path2
```

After that I decided to create a function to do the exact same thing, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

arr = np.random.randint(1, 100, size = (2, 5, 5)) #3D array


def shortest(prices):

    for i in arr:
        graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
        path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight')
        return path

print(shortest(arr))
```

and I got the next output:

```
[0, 1, 3] #same as path 1
```

And if I if change the position of the "return path" like this:

```
def shortest(precios):

    for i in arr:
        graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
        path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight')
    return path

print(shortest(arr))
```

I got the next output:

```
[0, 3] #same as path 2
```

I can't get the the two paths in the same output using my function. Any idea what is happening here? I was practicing using functions in python since I'm kinda new in the topic, so I was hoping you can help me seeing what is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `networkx` or `numpy`; this is simple control flow.  Your "shortest path" loop iterates through the supplied graphs and finds the shortest path for each.

The non-function version prints each path as it's found -- still dealing with only one at a time.  Since you made no provision in your function to aggregate the found solutions, you still get only one at a time ... which, for a function, means you get only one.

This code returns as soon as it finds the first solution:

```
for i in arr:
    graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
    path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight')
    return path   # The function ends as soon as it gets here: you get only the first solution.
```

This code finds all the solutions, but you throw away each one as soon as you find the next:

```
for i in arr:
    graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
    path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight')
    # You just deleted the previous solution, and replaced it with another.

return path
```

This returns only the *last* solution, as that's the only one you didn't overwrite.  You have to somehow accumulate the solutions and return them together, or alter your function usage.  For instance:

```
all_path = []
for i in arr:
    graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
    all_path.append( nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 3, weight = 'weight') )

return all_path
```

Comment: Ohh! I get it, so I create a new list and the stored the solutions! Thank you so much!